# Django foreign key query, why it returns None?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

When I try to query foreign keys using get(), I always get `None` values, even though I know they are set to 1 in the DB. Am I missing something here? Should I do something different to get the foreignkey values?

Here's what the code looks like:

```
class Car_to_brand( models.Model ):
    brand_id = models.ForeignKey( Brand, db_column='brand_id' )
    ...

class Brand( models.Model ):
    (id is not defined here but it's the primary key)
    ...

print Car_to_brand.__dict__.get( brand_id )
```

That would give me `{brand_id:None}`, but it should be `{brand_id:1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have named your field `brand_id` and not brand. `get(brand_id)` is returning None, because there the key `brand_id` is not in the dictionary. If you print `car.__dict__`, you will see that it contains `brand_id_id` instead.

However, **it is highly unusual to access attributes using `instance.__dict__.get()`**. Try the following instead:

```
class Car( models.Model ):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand) # don't need to set db_column, brand_id is the default


car.brand_id # this is the id of the brand (e.g. 1) that this car is linked to 
car.brand # this is the brand instance
```

Comment: Thanks! you were right it contains brand_id_id instead of brand_id... That was my problem.

Comment: Alasdair: Shouldn't that last line be `car.brand.id`?  There's no field in Car for `brand_id`.

Comment: @Elf: No, I do mean `car.brand_id`. Perhaps my '# comment' wasn't clear, I've tried to clarify it. If you have a foreign key `car.brand`, you can access the id as `car.brand_id`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation. `car.brand.id` would cause an extra lookup for django to fetch the brand from the db.

Comment: @Alasdair: `pipeline.user`: "elfsternberg" but `pipeline.user_id`: "AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'user_id'"  The docs you linked to state that it creates a table with the *column name* "brand_id", not that it creates an attribute on the object with that name.

Comment: @Elf: You're right, the link to the docs isn't very helpful. I can't find a better one at the moment. But for *all* my foreign keys I have just tested, I can access `instance.fk_field` and `instance.fk_field_id`. Without seeing the model definition for `Pipeline`, I don't know why `pipeline.user_id` raises `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to tell Django how to do its job.  The field isn't "brand_id" for a foreign key, it's just "brand," because although the "Car" table (in my example below, I've renamed your model) only has the ID of the brand, when you dereference `somecar.brand` Django will hand you an instance of the brand object associated with it.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    carname = models.TextField()

class Brand(models.Model):
    brandname = models.TextField() # supplied for example
```

That creates a relationship between a car and its brand.  That's all you need.

Now you can say things like

```
 car = Car.objects.get(carname = "Corvette")
 print car.brand.brandname # prints "Chevrolet" unless your database is hosed.
 print car.brand.id # prints the unique key Django uses to keep track of these relationships
```

As for the last line of your example, what are you trying to do?  `Car_to_brand` is a class that describes a database object; it is not an object itself, and so while it describes a relationship to brand, it does not have a brand of its own.

---

A bit of clarity about that last sentence.  `Car_to_brand` is a Python object in the sense that everything in python is an object of some sort, but it is a Class object that describes a database table, its accessors and relationships.  It is not a Django database object.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that clarified the right usage of Django.