# Why can't i display my model foreign key instance in Django?

Tags: django

This worked just fine in my other project but now it doesn't work. Is there something wrong with my code? I followed these but nothing worked for me: [How to display Foreign key Data in Django view page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497988/how-to-display-foreign-key-data-in-django-view-page), [How to access foreign key in a django template? (DetailView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069689/how-to-access-foreign-key-in-a-django-template-detailview), [Django foreign key query, why it returns None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276735/django-foreign-key-query-why-it-returns-none)

**models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author_name')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    author_info = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='author_info', default=None, null=True)
```

**html template (this one is a generic.DetailView)**

```
{{ post.author_info.description }}
```

EDIT:

**views.py**

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/blog_detail.html'
```

Comment: can you add your views?

Comment: sure thing. please see my new edit

Comment: use **`{{ object.author_info.description }}`** instead of `{{ post.author_info.description }}`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu follow stack overflow guidelines . Don't give answer in comments. Thanks

Comment: Can I have that *guideline* reference which indicates I shouldn't comment *something that "likely to be an answer"*? @MuhammadFaizanFareed

Comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "Thanks" ".  You can give answers in comments when question is closed or you don't have clear answer.   You can read this         https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments

Comment: Does this post suggest *"Don't give answer in comments"*?

Answer (score 0):

From [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) documentation

> While this view is executing, self.object will contain the object that
> the view is operating upon.

so `{{ object.author_info.description }}`

or set `context_object_name` if you are willing to change default object name

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/blog_detail.html'
    context_object_name='post'
```